# c gtk+-2 glade3: adding text to a combobox loaded from Gtk Builder

Tags: c, combobox, gtk, glade

I'm learning GTK+2 and glade 3. I'm trying to add a text to a combobox component i loaded from Gtk Builder.

i use the following code:

```
output_right_combobox = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"output_right_combobox"));
gtk_combo_box_append_text (GTK_COMBO_BOX(output_left_combobox),"aaa");
```

I get the following critical error on the gtk_combo_box_append_text line:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_combo_box_append_text: assertion `GTK_IS_LIST_STORE (combo_box->priv->model)' failed
```

It semes that I need to use GtkListStore for that, but I cannot find a way to use it and add it to the combobox. any ideas ?

## update

I tried doing the following:

```
    GtkTreeIter iter;
GtkListStore *store = gtk_list_store_new (1, G_TYPE_STRING);
gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter);
gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter, 0, "foo", -1);

gtk_combo_box_set_model (GTK_COMBO_BOX(output_right_combobox), (GtkTreeModel *)store);
```

but the combobox list in the application is still empty.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a GtkCellRenderer to your combobox to get it to render the text:

```
gtk_combo_box_set_model (GTK_COMBO_BOX (output_right_combobox), GTK_TREE_MODEL(store));

GtkCellRenderer * cell = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
gtk_cell_layout_pack_start( GTK_CELL_LAYOUT( output_right_combobox ), cell, TRUE );
gtk_cell_layout_set_attributes( GTK_CELL_LAYOUT( output_right_combobox ), cell, "text", 0, NULL );
```

Answer (score 0):

First populate the list then make it visible with `GtkCellRenderer`:

```
GtkTreeIter iter;
GtkListStore *store = gtk_list_store_new(1,G_TYPE_STRING);
GtkCellRenderer *cell = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

gtk_list_store_append(store,&iter);
gtk_list_store_set(store,&iter,0,"1st list item",-1);
gtk_list_store_append(store,&iter);
gtk_list_store_set(store,&iter,0,"2nd list item",-1);

gtk_combo_box_set_model(GTK_COMBO_BOX(my_combo_box), GTK_TREE_MODEL(store));
gtk_cell_layout_pack_start(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(my_combo_box), cell, "text",0,NULL);
gtk_combo_box_set_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(my_combo_box),0);
```